# How to group objects by values

Tags: kotlin

I have an object that looks like this:

```
data class Product(val name: String,
                   val maker: List<String>)
```

Currently, the response that I receive from the backend (and it can't be changed) is as follows:

```
[{"name":"Car", "maker":["Audi"]},
 {"name":"Car", "maker":["BMW"]},
 {"name":"Motorcycle", "maker":["Yamaha"]},
 {"name":"Motorcycle", "maker":["Kawasaki"]}
]
```

The actual list consists of a lot of data, but the `name` field can be trusted to be grouped by.
What would be a way for me to map this data so that the end result is something like this:

```
[{"name":"Car", "maker":["Audi", "BMW"]},
 {"name":"Motorcycle", "maker":["Yamaha","Kawasaki"]}
]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use `groupBy { ... }` and then process the groups map entries, replacing them with a single `Product`:

```
val result = products.groupBy { it.name }.entries.map { (name, group) ->
    Product(name, group.flatMap { it.maker })
}
```

Comment: That help me a lot. Thanks!